# How to protect sensitive information such as a software licence?

Tags: .net, cryptography, public-key-encryption

My goal is to protect the licence information of a software product. The client that uses the platform should not be able alter it, should not be able to crack it.

**Let me provide some context that is specific to my solution:**
In order for the platform to work, it must connect to a **REST API** in order to get the licence. The platform will make these requests periodically to check if there are any changes in the licence. The requested licence will be cached, somewhere in the platform's database.

Things I have considered:

1. **Encrypting the licence in the client database**:  Because the platform needs to use parameters held by the licence, I don't see how encryption can be achieved without **exposing the private key to the platform**. The way I see it, if we expose the private key to the platform, then some malicious user can use it to alter he's licence.
2. **Signing data**: Another way of looking at it, is to sign the data, and if someone changes the data, we can take appropriate actions. Since we can create a signature using the private key, and use the signature and the public key on the client platform to compare it, we will not expose the private key. The problem that I see here is that they can **override the key pair with their own**, meaning that they can create a dummy server that signs the document with their own private key and then use their own public key to check the signature. Would having an intelligent key management system nullify this threat?

I know that in a normal use case, it's in the clients best interest to protect his platform, but because of the nature of the platform, I have to assume that the client platform is a hostile  environment.

**How would you solve this problem? Is there some obvious solution that I am missing?**

Comment: This is just the DRM problem re-stated.  Stackoverflow will not be able to give you a solution to DRM until/unless Intel SGX becomes ubiquitous.

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson: I was not aware of this. Thank you for giving me  a lead to follow.

Comment: There are commercial and open source libraries in this area to provide licensing control. Just use Google and you will see a lot.

Comment: Start with your second approach and throw as much obfuscation/any reversing techniques at it as you can. That doesn't make it unbreakable, but perhaps it discourages some attackers.